# Vue 3 lint in VS Code is confused

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs3

I was very happy with Vue 2 and VS Code, but with Vue 3 and **Velur**, I get this kind of issues:

[image]

You notice `VoteBtn` is imported and used above, but the linter complains. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Maybe ESLint is a solution for you, it's a node module. I use Vue3, TypeScript with ESLint and I'm very happy with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue because I had installed both Volar and Vetur.

Just remove Vetur and it will do the trick.